# Does cocos2d-x force multiple inheritance?

Tags: c++, cocos2d-x

I have a class,

```
class Ticket : public cocos2d::CCNode, public cocos2d::CCTargetedTouchDelegate { ... };
```

Which works fine when I register for touch events on that node using:

```
CCDirector::sharedDirector()->getTouchDispatcher()->addTargetedDelegate(ticket_, 0, true);
```

However, if I alter my class so that it uses composition rather than inheritance for the CCNode bit:

```
class Ticket : public cocos2d::CCTargetedTouchDelegate {
private:
  cocos2d::CCNode* node_;
public:
  Ticket() { node_ = new CCNode(); node_->init(); }
  cocos2d::CCNode* node() { return node_; }
  ...
};
```

Then the following blows up with a SIGSEGV 11:

```
CCDirector::sharedDirector()->getTouchDispatcher()->addTargetedDelegate(ticket_, 0, true);
```

I have added ticket_->node() to the current layer, but I am wondering if the touch dispatcher somehow doesn't like the node and the delegate to be different things. Or to put it another way, is touch dispatcher is expecting the node and the delegate to be the same thing?

So in short, my code works when I use multiple inheritance, but it doesn't when I use composition. Without delving into the framework, can anyone say that this is true, or have I just missed something obvious? I am using cocos2d-2.1rc0-x-2.1.2

Comment: at least in cocos2d-iphone the touch dispatcher works with non-node classes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it seems cocos2d-x indeed does force multiple inheritance. It expects the touch delegate to be dynamically castable to a CCObject, which your Ticket class isn't when you use composition. When you inherit from CCNode, which itself inherits from CCObject, you're in the clear. You can see the problem [here](https://github.com/cocos2d/cocos2d-x/blob/41dd7ec297a455bfff09354d824df116e4e759f5/cocos2dx/touch_dispatcher/CCTouchHandler.cpp#L96) on github.

This does not seem to be a mistake though, since the documentation actually hints at this by noting

> IMPORTANT: The delegate will be retained.

for CCTouchDispatcher::addTargetedDelegate.